# Django Path.home() giving servers directory instead of users home directory

Tags: python, django

I am on a Django Project. Using version 4 and Python 3.10.
I want to download file and my code is :

```
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads").replace('\\','/')
            if not os.path.isdir(f"{downloads_path}/{str(row['CUSTOMER NAME'])}"):
                os.makedirs(f"{downloads_path}/{str(row['CUSTOMER NAME'])}")

            pdf.output(f"{downloads_path}/{str(row['CUSTOMER NAME'])}/document.pdf")
```

`downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads").replace('\\','/')`
Giving me **PermissionError : [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/Downloads'**

Its working on my local server but not in my live server. It is looking for my server's home location instead of my computers home directory.
Permission :
[image]

Comment: Is the server running under the `www-data` user?

Comment: Server is running under virtualmin and only media and static folders are given www-data permission. I updated my question with the image.

Comment: If you're using Virtualmin, nothing should be owned by www-data. All site data should be owned by the domain. You should not be hosting stuff in /var/www on a system using virtual hosts as configured by Virtualmin. Every domain has a home, and every home has a public_html dir; put your files there.

Comment: @swelljoe I changed ownership of media and static folder because of permission error and my app is not hosted in /var/www .. it is located in my user folder /public_html/folder. I don;t know from where its getting this var/www .. It is nowhere configured. Even apache conf for domain is not pointed there.

Comment: It's obviously configured somewhere.

Comment: Nope. Atleast not by me. I searched in every path but there is no settings for this. Rest of my app is working. I can download file from media directory. Is my only this chunk is wrong ?